# Module not found: you attempted to import react which falls outside of the project src dir/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, lerna

My team has a large react app that is a monorepo via lerna.  Everything was going okay until we noticed our bundle had become around 6MB. I began looking into it and realized that we were not hoisting common dependencies.

Our build process has been

> npm install
>   lerna bootstrap
>   npm run build:app

And this creates our traditional bundle just fine
I thought that I could simply replace

> lerna bootstrap

with

> lerna bootstrap --hoist

But this causes our build process to throw the exception

> Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /myAppBuild/packages/myApp/node_modules/react which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

If I do the following

> npm install
>   lerna bootstrap
>   lerna bootstrap --hoist
>   npm run build:app

then it works just fine.  I know the issue is something to do with the node_modules and dependencies, but can anyone help pinpoint exactly where?

Comment: Lerna doesn't "hoisting common dependencies" by default. You should add param --hoist. But the problem is the issue with "Module not found: Error: You attempted to import". Do you try last lerna version?